# Mac OS X equivalent of 32feet's C# bluetooth

Tags: c#, macos, mono, bluetooth, 32feet

I have worked with **32feet's** ***.NET Library*** on a project that I'm looking to port to the ***Mono Runtime***.

However, as ***32feet*** is written in ***C/C++*** for ***Windows*** and then wrapped to be used in ***.NET***, I am looking for an equivalent.

I've been scouting the internet for an alternative for the past 3 days, and came up empty handed, so now is the time to ask for help

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't going to be a direct equivalent.
What you can do however is use 
http://www.monobjc.net/
to wire up https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/_index.html to your app.

Comment: This looks very nice. I'll definately looking into this, to find if it'll integrate propperly with the rest of my code.

Comment: Looks like you have to run things in a special monoobjc runtime? That is a no go for me, as I have to link to it from the runtime that is within Unity, and that is a standard Mono runtime :/